# How to name pandas dataframe columns from a text file

Tags: pandas

I have two text files, one is data and one is the headers.

The data looks like this in dataframe:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6Xya.png)
And the headers text file looks like this:

```
`[TramDateDimension]
(
       [Date]
      ,[CalendarYear]
      ,[FinancialYear]
      ,[FinancialMonth]
      ,[CalendarMonth]
      ,[CalendarMonthSeq]
      ,[CalendarQuarter]
      ,[FinancialQuarter]
      ,[CalendarWeek]...)
`
```

How can I name the columns using this text file?

Comment: read the txt file line by line, remove braces ,  apply it to df

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First return all values between `[]` with regex:

```
import re
with open("headers.txt") as f:
        s = ''.join(f.readlines())
        headers = re.findall('\[(.*?)\]',s)

print (headers)
['TramDateDimension', 'Date', 'CalendarYear', 'FinancialYear', 
 'FinancialMonth', 'CalendarMonth', 'CalendarMonthSeq', 
 'CalendarQuarter', 'FinancialQuarter', 'CalendarWeek']
```

And then call [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with parameter `names` with `header[1:]` to remove the first value of the list of headers:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', names=headers[1:])
```